# Typescript overloads ignored after the first overload

Tags: javascript, typescript

### Problem

When creating an overload method for a specific method, now call to it only works for the first defined overload. 
If the call works with the second overload, It raises an error because the typing are not corresponding to the first overload definition.

### Example

I have an `AxiosWrapper` Class that I created so I could add some overloads method.
The generic function prototype of Axios is the last one.

```js
export interface MeiliAxiosWrapperInterface {
  post(
    url: string,
    data: IndexRequest,
  ): Promise<IndexResponse>
  post<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<EnqueuedUpdate>>(
    url: string,
    data?: T,
  ): Promise<R>
}

// axios-wrapper.ts
import * as Types from './types'
class AxiosWrapper implements Types.MeiliAxiosWrapper {
  post(
    url: string,
    data: Types.IndexRequest,
  ): Promise<Types.IndexResponse>
  post<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<Types.EnqueuedUpdate>>(
    url: string,
    data?: T,
  ): Promise<R> {
    return this.instance.post(url, data, config) // this.instance is an axios instance
  }
}
```

#### Success

This implementations works great with this method (the class in which this method is present extends the AxiosWrapper, so this.post uses the AxiosWrapper):

```js
class Client extends AxiosWrapper {
  //...
  async createIndex(data: Types.IndexRequest): Promise<Indexes> {
    const url = `/indexes`

    const index = await this.post(url, data);
    return new Indexes(this.config, index.uid)
  }
}
```

#### Fails

On this method it used to work when i was only using the default axios prototype. But now that I have added an overload it fails:

```js
class Indexes extends AxiosWrapper implements Types.Indexes {
  //...
  addDocuments(
      documents: Types.Document[],
    ): Promise<Types.EnqueuedUpdate> {
      const url = `/indexes/${this.indexUid}/documents`

      return this.post(url, documents)
  }
}
```

with this **error** being raised:

```sh
Argument of type 'Document<any>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IndexRequest'.
  Property 'uid' is missing in type 'Document<any>[]' but required in type 'IndexRequest'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error was that I didn't add the final overload which is not supposed to be used for comparison but just for code.

```js
export interface MeiliAxiosWrapperInterface {
  post(
    url: string,
    data: IndexRequest,
  ): Promise<IndexResponse>
  post<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<EnqueuedUpdate>>(
    url: string,
    data?: T,
  ): Promise<R>
}

// axios-wrapper.ts
import * as Types from './types'
class AxiosWrapper implements Types.MeiliAxiosWrapper {
  post(
    url: string,
    data: Types.IndexRequest,
  ): Promise<Types.IndexResponse>
  post<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<Types.EnqueuedUpdate>>(
    url: string,
    data?: T,
  ): Promise<R>
post(
    url: string,
    data?: any,
  ): Promise<any> {
    return this.instance.post(url, data, config) // this.instance is an axios instance
  }
}
```